# How does d3.tsv("file.tesv").row(function(d,i){//action}).get(error,rows) work

Tags: d3.js

I want to know how does the following

```
d3.tsv("file.tesv").row(function(d,i){
    //action
}).get(error, rows)
```

works because sometimes my program goes to `row` and sometimes it goes inside `.get` . Could someone please tell me how does this work?

Comment: There is no `d3.get` function.

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake. I changed it to d3.tsv now

Comment: Well the function in `.row()` is passed every row of the file. The result of that is then passed to the function in `.get()`.

Comment: Result in the sense? the number of rows get passed into .get(error,rows) ?

Comment: A data structure containing all rows.

Comment: There's a good explanation in the documentation: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV. The row function is used to map each row while loading (very useful to parse strings as numbers, for example), while the get function then does something interesting and/or useful with the complete load.